# C# ASP.NET, SQL Server : Button Click inserts duplicate rows

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a registration form where on button click a stored procedure in a SQL Server is called and a new row is inserted. The problem is when I click (no accidental double clicks) two rows of the same entry is inserted. I have gone through my codes thoroughly but I could not find the issue.

C# button click code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int userId = 0;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["islamguiderConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand insertUser = new SqlCommand("Register_Student"))
        {  
            insertUser.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", TextBox1.Text.ToUpper());
            insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox4.Text.ToLower());
            insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseCode", DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
            insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseTitle", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.ToString());

            insertUser.Connection = con;

            con.Open();
            insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();

            userId = Convert.ToInt32(insertUser.ExecuteScalar());
            Con.Close()
        }
    }
}
```

My SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Register_Student]
    @StudentName NVARCHAR(200),
    @Email NVARCHAR(200),
    @CourseCode NVARCHAR(200),
    @CourseTitle NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @ID INT 

    INSERT INTO dbo.Registration_Table (StudentName,Email, CourseCode, CourseTitle) 
    VALUES (@StudentName, @Email, @CourseCode, @CourseTitle)  

    SELECT 2
END
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in these two lines :

```
   insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();

   userId = Convert.ToInt32(insertUser.ExecuteScalar());
```

You're executing the `insertUser` Command twice; in `ExecuteNonQuery` and in `ExecuteScalar` .

Comment: Oh yes.. thank u. i have overlooked that.. Let me edit and verify